# How to add my own method to the built-in str type?

Tags: python, string, class, methods

```
def change(s):
    result=""
    for index,item in enumerate(s):
        if(index%2 !=0): result=result+item
    return(result)
```

This function can extract all of the even characters from a string into a new string:

```
>>> x="hallo world"
>>> change(x)
'al ol'
```

1. How can I make it into a method on the `str` class?  When you input  `x.change()`  in the Python console, I would get the same output as `change(x)`. `x.change()` will get `'al ol'`.
2. `dir(x)` will get `'change'` in the output such as:

   ```
   ['__add__', '__class__', ...omitted..., 'zfill', 'change']
   ```

Comment: Not sure but you can create your own module with different name than sting and save it in `/usr/lib/python2.7/` or the lib directory.

Comment: I'd call them the odd characters from a string, since Python uses 0-based indexing. Also, I realise this is just an example of a custom method, but FWIW you can do what your `change()` method does with slicing: `"hallo world"[1::2] -> 'al ol'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this.  Well, at least not directly.  Python does not allow you add custom methods/attributes to the built-in types.  It is simply a law of the language.

You could however make your own string type by [subclassing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) (inheriting from) `str`:

```
class MyStr(str):
    def change(self): # 's' argument is replaced by 'self'
        result=""
        for index,item in enumerate(self): # Use 'self' here instead of 's'
            if(index%2 !=0): result=result+item
        return(result)
```

Demo:

```
>>> class MyStr(str):
...     def change(self):
...         result=""
...         for index,item in enumerate(self):
...             if(index%2 !=0): result=result+item
...         return(result)
...
>>> x = MyStr("hallo world")
>>> x
'hallo world'
>>> x.change()
'al ol'
>>> 'change' in dir(x)
True
>>>
```

The new `MyStr` class will behave like the normal `str` class in every way.  In fact, it has all of the functionality found on `str`:

```
>>> x = MyStr("hallo world")
>>> x.upper()
'HALLO WORLD'
>>> x.split()
['hallo', 'world']
>>>
```

The only difference between the two is that `MyStr` has an added `change` method.

Comment: Also, just for clarification any string literal created will never be an instance of `MyStr`.

Comment: Any string literal created   by str class will   be an instance of str ,never be an instance of MyStr.
>>> x1=str("haha1")
>>> isinstance(x1,str)
True 
>>> isinstance(x1,MyStr)
False

Any string literal created   by MyStr class will   be  either  an instance of str or an instance of MyStr.
>>> x2=MyStr("haha2")
>>> isinstance(x2,MyStr)
True
>>> isinstance(x2,str)
True

Comment: @it_is_a_literature - Yes, that is expected because `MyStr` is a subclass of `str`.  `isinstance` takes into account inheritance.  If you need a direct test, you could always do `type(x) is MyStr`.  Note however that there is rarely a need to do this.